# Search multiple folders in multiple servers list

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a ps1 that can search multiple folders in multiple servers list, but seems didn't work. Something wrong with the *folder I guess. Sorry I'm very new to this.

```
    $folders = get-content "C:\temp\folders.txt"
    get-content c:\temp\servers.txt | Foreach {
    Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp" -include *folders -Recurse -ErrorAction 
    silentlycontinue} | export-csv c:\Temp\results.csv
```

Comment: Are the folders you want to search always nested under `C:\temp` somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I want to search multiple folders in c:/temp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading a textfile with (presumably) a list of server names to probe, but in your code you do nothing with that other than iterate this list..

Try

```
$folders = Get-Content 'C:\temp\folders.txt'   # the list of foldernames to look for
Get-Content 'C:\temp\servers.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    # construct a UNC path to the C:\Temp folder on the remote server  (\\server\c$\temp)
    # the $_ Automatic variable contains one servername in each iteration
    $remotePath = "\\$_\C$\temp"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $remotePath -Include $folders -Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    # select properties you need
    Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_}}, Name, FullName, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime
} | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

OR

Have the remote servers do the work and return the results to you. You may need to add -Credentials on Invoke-Command:

```
$folders = Get-Content 'C:\temp\folders.txt'   # the list of foldernames to look for
Get-Content 'C:\temp\servers.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { 
        # this is running on the remote computer, so it uses it's own LOCAL path
        # the $folders variable needs to be scoped '$using:folders', otherwise it is unknown in the scriptblock
        Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp' -Include $using:folders -Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        # select and output the properties you need
        Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}}, Name, FullName, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. I currently running a command (Test-Path \\xxxxxxxxxx\f$\foldername) to test path and it's very inefficient. This script works now and able to choose what column in result. I will use this script output to do the rest. Thanks again !!